# Speed up dnorm function

Tags: r, performance

I have some R-Script, which takes too much time. After profiling I did realize that most time got spent by the function `dnorm`. The input of `dnorm` is a matrix of size 11000 x 11000. Correspondingly the output is a matrix of the same size, too. What do you think, how is it possible to speed up `dnorm`? Any idea is welcome and would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I doubt that dnorm can be made faster.  Your problem is O(N^2), where N = 11,000.  Maybe you can take advantage of symmetry, but that depends on your problem.

Comment: Do you have some reason you need to generate `1.21E8` values?  Please tell the **actual task** you want to solve, not how you want to solve it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like @duffymo said, you have an O(n^2) problem here, so there's not going to be any dramatic speedup.  The only thing I can think of is computing `dnorm` explicitly yourself.  This seems to result in a moderate improvement of about 40% on my machine.  For example, if your normal distribution parameters are `(0,1)` then:

```
> x<-rnorm(10^7)
> system.time(dx<-dnorm(x))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.945   0.004   0.949 
> system.time(dx0<-exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.559   0.000   0.560 
> max(abs(dx0-dx))
[1] 5.551115e-17
```

Not sure why this happens exactly.  Maybe R computes the square root individually for each value in the vector if you call `dnorm`.

On edit: here are times for 100 samples:

```
> microbenchmark(dx0<-exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi),dx<-dnorm(x))
Unit: milliseconds
                            expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq
 dx0 <- exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2 * pi) 481.5091 508.1434 522.1289 511.9739  519.9924
                  dx <- dnorm(x) 944.4744 991.4800 998.2794 995.0194 1004.2889
       max neval
  752.3929   100
 1149.2694   100
```

On edit again.  Another thing you could do is compute `dnorm` in parallel.  You can do this straight from R using Rcpp (assuming `(0,1)` -- you can easily adjust this for other parameters):

```
require(Rcpp)
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-fopenmp")
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS"="-fopenmp")
sourceCpp(code = '#include <Rcpp.h>
  #include <omp.h>
  using namespace Rcpp;
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  NumericVector dnormpar(NumericVector x){
  double c = 1/sqrt(2*PI);  
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector ret(n);
  #pragma omp parallel for if(n> 50000)
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    ret[i] = exp(-x[i]*x[i]/2)*c;
  return ret;
}')
```

The amount of improvement you get depends on the number of cores you have.  I get about an 8x improvement over my first suggestion:

```
> dx1<-dnormpar(x)
> max(abs(dx1-dx))
[1] 8.470329e-22
> microbenchmark(dx1<-dnormpar(x))
Unit: milliseconds
               expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 dx1 <- dnormpar(x) 39.9888 65.60082 74.03912 68.81251 71.35201 226.9584   100
```

Final edit.  Here's a version that takes both a mean and standard deviation, with R's behavior of looping repeatedly over mu or sigma if they shorter than x.

```
require(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(code = '#include <Rcpp.h>
  #include <omp.h>
  using namespace Rcpp;
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  NumericVector dnormpar2(NumericVector x, NumericVector mu, NumericVector sig){
  double c = 1/sqrt(2*PI);  
  int n = x.size();
  int muSize = mu.size();
  int sigSize = sig.size();
  NumericVector ret(n);
  double x0,s0;
  #pragma omp parallel for if(n> 50000) private(x0,s0)
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
    s0 = sig[i % sigSize];
    x0 = x[i]-mu[i % muSize];
    ret[i] = exp(-x0*x0/(2*s0*s0))*c/s0;
  }
  return ret;
}')
```

In R:

```
> mu<-rnorm(length(x))
> sig<-runif(length(x))
> dx<-dnorm(x,mu,sig)
> dx2<-dnormpar2(x,mu,sig)
> max(abs(dx-dx2))
[1] 1.136868e-13
```

Comment: Speed  difference in **system** time is inconsequential -- you might try running 100 cases to see if this really exists.

Comment: If the OP really needs a gazillion random samples, which I doubt, he could always use `parallel` to use all his cores (if he has a decent machine, at least :-) )

Comment: I've found `system.time` pretty reliable for tasks that take a reasonable amount of time, say 1 second or more.  In this case `microbenchmark` confirms that it's almost twice as fast to calculate `dnorm` explicitly.

Comment: `dnorm` is implemented in C: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/nmath/dnorm.c As you can see that implementation does more checks.

Comment: @Roland, I don't think it's the checks, I think it's the fact that it computes the denominator individually for each element in the vector.  sqrt is a relatively expensive operation.

Comment: As far as I see it doesn't. There is a constant defined (search for  `M_1_SQRT_2PI`.

Comment: You're right.  Looking at the code, seems it makes two calls to `exp` to increase accuracy by breaking up `x` into a large and small piece.  That might account for the difference.  I don't think the checks take very long.  So my version is faster but less accurate.

Comment: @mrip Rcpp version is the best solution! It works considerably faster! Thanks a lot, you made my day!

Comment: @mrip is it possible to implement in Rcpp part also the attribute `sd` (standard deviation)?

Comment: I added another version that accepts mean and standard deviation as parameters.  If you're going to go this route, you're probably going to want to add some parameter checking somewhere.  I don't know what happens if you pass `NA` or `sigma=0` or something like that.